# Limit 10 records from posts for each category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two table `categories` and `posts`, I don't want to get all records for each category. I want to get limited rows from each category.

`categories` table as below :-

1. ID
2. Name
3. Slug

`posts` table as below :-

1. ID [ PK ]
2. title
3. slug
4. content
5. category [Key - Foreign key]
6. publish_date

What i am trying to achieve is , I want to get 10 records from `posts` for each `category`.

What i am doing at the moment is so dangerous, that it runs lots of query, i want to minimize it to 1 query.

```
<?php

    $fetchCat = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from categories");
    while($row = $fetchCat->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fetchPost = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, slug from posts where category=".$mysqli->real_escape_string($row['id'])." limit 10");
        // Processing my code.
    }
?>
```

can i have some "`inner join`" query, which can reduce my query to 1-2 query and get me same results as above one ?

I want to have 10 articles for each category to be fetched. In future, i may have 40-45 category, and for each category , on an average, i may have 80-90 posts. While fetching all posts for 40-45 category from above method, can take my application on coaster ride. So i need some feasible method, where i can limit my posts record for each 40-45 category.

This is not simple inner join, where i am fetching posts, but this is actually limiting the inner join records to display for each parent table.

Comment: Do you care about which 10 u get bak 4 a given cat. Index on slug columns or no? How many rows in each tbl

Comment: How many category do you have ?

Comment: @Ala I have approx 12-14 categories.

Comment: @AsConfused , I want 10 records for each category.

Comment: Right we know that. Which ones any? How manys rows in post

Comment: @AsConfused , There are probably 278 rows in posts and some category have only 2 posts and some have 80 posts.

Comment: do a search for "mysql groupwise limit".  look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: @AsConfused , Thanks a lot man, for going through my query and letting me know "analyze table" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution in 2 query. There was little improvement.

1st Query, I ran for category and stored them in an array.

```
$cat_array = array();
$fetchCat = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from categories");
while($rowCat = $fetchCat->fetch_assoc()) {
   // Category processing....
}
```

Second Query , i ran against post using `group_concat` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get `10` records of each category.

```
$post_array = array();
$fetchPost = $mysqli->query("select category, 
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(id), ',', 10) as post_id, 
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(title), ',', 10) as post_title, 
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(slug), ',', 10) as post_slug from posts 
             group by category;");

while($rowPost = $fetchPost->fetch_assoc()) {
    $post_array[ $rowPost['category'] ] [id] = $rowPost['post_id'];
    $post_array[ $rowPost['category'] ] [title] = $rowPost['post_title'];
    $post_array[ $rowPost['category'] ] [slug] = $rowPost['post_slug'];
}
```

2 Query and all required data [ `categories` table data, 10 `posts` table data from each category ]

I had to do some explode for `post_id` , `post_title`, `post_slug` and use it in my application.

Now, **to get list of all title and slug for any category, it was simple, eg, for category id "1"** all i had to do is :-

```
$post_array[1][id]  // Returns all post_id associated with category 1.
```

A great thank for @billynoah, for pointing me in "group wise" direction, "AsConfused" for going through my query and letting me know, there is command `analyze table posts` too.

Thanks